# std::vector, thread-safety, multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am using std::vector as shared data in a multi-threaded application. I encapsulate the thread inside a class, e.g.,

```
class ABC {
public:
    double a, b, c;
};

boost::mutex mutex1;

class XYZ {
public:
    XYZ(vector<ABC> & pVector) {
        ptrVector = &pVector;
        m_thread = boost::thread(&XYZ::Start, this);
    }
    ~XYZ() {}
    void Start();
public:
    vector<ABC> * ptrVector;
    boost::thread m_thread;  
};    

void XYZ::Start() {
    try {
        while(1) {
            boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
            for (unsigned int i=0; i<ptrVector->size(); i++) {
                {
                    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex1);
                    ptrVector->at(i).a = double(rand())/10000;  
                    ptrVector->at(i).b = double(rand())/10000;
                    ptrVector->at(i).c = double(rand())/10000;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted) {}
    catch(std::exception) {} 
}
```

When I close the application, **sometimes**, in the debug, there will be 2 error messages, **sometimes** there will be no error messages. I often heard people talking about std::vector being not thread-safe, is this one of the cases? I am using Visual Studio 2008, boost thread, the size of the vector is fixed. Can anyone also offer some advice on how to use std::vector in a multi-threaded application.

1. First-chance exception at 0x7688b9bc in ETP.exe: Microsoft C++
   exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x02d8f7bc..
2. First-chance exception at 0x00e916e0 in ETP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
   violation reading location 0x00000008.
3. Second Chance Assertion Failed: File c:\program files
   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vector, Line Second
   Chance Assertion Failed: File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
   visual studio 9.0\vc\include\vector98

Thanks.

Comment: vector is not thread safe, if you try to write to it at the same time from different threads then it will break. You are locking it though, and without other code to see how you are using it, it is impossible to tell what might be going wrong. This particular code by itself looks fine.

Comment: Apart from thread safety, probably you also need to take in to account the sequence in which your threads access the vector, If one thread is reading from the vector then you should ensure the other thread has written to the vector before it or atleast Your code should handle the condition that vector has not been written to.

Comment: @Jarryd you are rite , in this code it seems that he's locking the vector using mutex , if he does so , then it shouldn't cause problem, for details we need to go though the complete code

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually, it is **absolutely** pointless to state `X` is or is not thread-safe! You need to qualify for what kind of uses. For example, hardly any class will be "thread-safe" when it is somehow used in one thread and destroyed in another.

That said, the statement that `std::vector<T>` is not thread- safe, independent of how often it is repeated, is **wrong**. However, it seems most people neither understand nor appreciate the thread-safety guarantees given. `std::vector<T>` is thread-safe in the following sense:

- You can read a vector object from multiple threads simultaneously.
- If there is one thread changing a vector object, there shall be neither concurrent readers or writers.
- Accesses to a vector object don't interfere with other vector objects.

This applies to vector structure itself. Accesses to contained object are bound to whatever rules are imposed on them. These are apparently not the thread-safety guarantees many people have in mind but anything stronger won't work with the container interface.

Comment: Sorry, but completely disagree with you, thread-safe is a known definition that states that the implementation should guarantee the concurrent (thread) protecting it shared areas to avoid conflicts, this means that a class is thread safe or not, stating that it depends on the usage means that it's not thread-safe!, how can be this the right answer?

Comment: You can read from multiple thread simultaneously. Yes - so long as a release memory barrier took place after it's last modification and a matching acquire memory barrier has occurred on all reading threads...

Comment: @Dietmar do you have a source on this?

Comment: @small_cat_destroyer: are you asking where the thread-safety guarantees I describe above are specified? That is in the library introduction, more precisely in [res.on.data.races], and actually applies to all standard library classes "unless specified otherwise".

Answer (score 4):

You call `ptrVector->size()` without locking it first. This could easily be the cause of your problems. Make sure to lock your vector before any reads or writes.

Comment: He said that the size of the vector is fixed, so that shouldn't cause a problem. However, since we don't have more code, we don't know if he's adding to it in a thread-unsafe manner without knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this instead?

concurrent_vector... from the Intel Threading Building Blocks

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/467758

Answer (score 0):

To add to what has been said above by Dietmar Kühl, when he states that thread safety

> ... applies to vector structure itself. Accesses to contained object
> are bound to whatever rules are imposed on them.

it is indeed possible to access the contiguous area of memory allocated by a vector from multiple writing threads, as long as each thread accesses different elements of the vector. For example, to populate an array of ten thousand elements from ten threads, first set the size of the vector to ten thousand, then pass a pointer to the block of memory starting at element 0, 1000, 2000, ... etc., to each thread, which can happily write to its block of a thousand elements. That will work correctly as long as no thread calls any function that could result in a reallocation of the vector's storage.