# Run method and wait to finish all for loops openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

I creathed in C++ method to find number's dividors. Second step was to use openmp in c++.
Unfortunatelly I can't manage why my function `doStuff` throws `memory error`. Probably the problem is with threads and I check arrays before all threads stop.. Could someone help me?

There is no need to read all my program, the problem is in `doStuff()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include "omp.h"

using namespace std;

vector<int> dividors;
int NUMBER = 1000;

bool ifContains(vector<int> element, int dividedNumber)
{
    for(int i=0; i<dividors.size(); i++)
    {
        if(dividors[i] == dividedNumber)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void doStuff()
{
    int sqr = (int) sqrt(NUMBER);
    int sqrp1 = sqr + 1;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
    #pragma omp for nowait
        for (int i = 1; i < sqrp1; i++)
        {
            if (NUMBER % i == 0)
            {
                if (!ifContains(dividors, i))
                    dividors.push_back(i);

                int dividednumber = NUMBER / i;

                if (!ifContains(dividors,dividednumber))
                    dividors.push_back(dividednumber);
            }
        }


        sort(dividors.begin(), dividors.end());

        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (int i = 0; i < dividors.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << dividors[i] << "\r\n";
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Also I tried this, but It doesn't work

```
void doStuff()
{
    int sqr = (int) sqrt(NUMBER);
    int sqrp1 = sqr + 1;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 1; i < sqrp1; i++)
        {

            if (NUMBER % i == 0)
            {
                if (!ifContains(dividors, i))
                    dividors.push_back(i);

                int dividednumber = NUMBER / i;

                if (!ifContains(dividors,dividednumber))
                    dividors.push_back(dividednumber);
            }
        }



        #pragma omp single
        sort(dividors.begin(), dividors.end());

        #pragma omp single
        for (int i = 0; i < dividors.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << dividors[i] << "\r\n";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `element` do?

Comment: it's array list storing dividors

Comment: Yes, you pass dividors to the ifContains method and it ends up in element, but you don't use element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to fix this.  The simplest is just to use the `ordered` clause.  See the code below.  However, this removes some of the parallelism.  A better way is to declare prviate dividors vectors (which I call `dividors_private`) inside the parallel block so that each thread get's it's own private version and then write to the `dividors` vector in critical block.  The sorting is done on the private vectors in parallel.  A final sort is done on `dividors` in a single thread but since most of it is already sorted it goes fast.  See the second code below:

The version of the code with ordered:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include "omp.h"

using namespace std;

vector<int> dividors;
int NUMBER = 1000;

bool ifContains(vector<int> dividors, int dividedNumber)
{
    for(int i=0; i<dividors.size(); i++)
    {
        if(dividors[i] == dividedNumber)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void doStuff()
{
    int sqr = (int) sqrt(NUMBER);
    int sqrp1 = sqr + 1;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for ordered
        for (int i = 1; i < sqrp1; i++)
        {

            if (NUMBER % i == 0)
            {
                #pragma omp ordered 
                {
                    dividors.push_back(i);
                    if (!ifContains(dividors, i))
                        dividors.push_back(i);

                    int dividednumber = NUMBER / i;

                    if (!ifContains(dividors, dividednumber))
                        dividors.push_back(dividednumber);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    sort(dividors.begin(), dividors.end());  
    for (int i = 0; i < dividors.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << dividors[i] << "\r\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

The version of the code which uses private dividors vectors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include "omp.h"

using namespace std;

vector<int> dividors;
int NUMBER = 1000;

bool ifContains(vector<int> dividors, int dividedNumber)
{
    for(int i=0; i<dividors.size(); i++)
    {
        if(dividors[i] == dividedNumber)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void doStuff()
{
    int sqr = (int) sqrt(NUMBER);
    int sqrp1 = sqr + 1;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        vector<int> dividors_private;
        #pragma omp for nowait
        for (int i = 1; i < sqrp1; i++)
        {

            if (NUMBER % i == 0)
            {

                dividors_private.push_back(i);
                //printf("i %d\n", i);
                if (!ifContains(dividors_private, i))
                    dividors_private.push_back(i);

                int dividednumber = NUMBER / i;

                if (!ifContains(dividors_private, dividednumber))
                    dividors_private.push_back(dividednumber);
            }
        }
        sort(dividors_private.begin(), dividors_private.end());
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            dividors.insert(dividors.end(), dividors_private.begin(), dividors_private.end());
        }
    }
    sort(dividors.begin(), dividors.end()); 
    for (int i = 0; i < dividors.size(); i++) 
    {
        cout << dividors[i] << "\r\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in gdb and am getting random crashed on the calls to `dividors.push_back(...)`. This seem to be a race condition and the reason is that you are changing the `dividors` vector from several threads at once and in this sense the `std::vector` class is not thread safe. See [std::vector, thread-safety, multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305315/stdvector-thread-safety-multi-threading).

What you have to do is to make sure that no thread changes the vector while another thread changes or reads it. This goes for sorting it on every thread to. Do it in a `#pragma omp single`, it only needs to be sorted once and especially not from several threads at once.