# Cast (C like) pointer to C++ matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, c++14, raw-pointer

I would like to pass matrix around from one function to another so I did:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int N = 2;

void init_matrix(int (*matrix)[N]) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
}

int main() 
{
    int *x = (int*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(int));
    init_matrix( (int (*)[N]) x );
    return 0;
}
```

How do I make the call to `init_matrix()` easier? I'm imagining it like `init_matrix(x, N)`.

Please note that, I'm kind of avoiding `std::vector` because I will play with parallel programming (pthreads, OpenMP, MPI) soon after. 
So I will ask for a solution without `std` approaches for building matrix.

Comment: Don't use `malloc`, `using namespace std` and (C style) arrays in C++. While at it, don't use `new` either. If you really need a matrix than [consider](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) creating one of your own.

Comment: You mean, its better to do int x[N][N]; So how would I receive this in `init_matrix`?

Comment: its better to build upon `std::vector` or `std::array` and not to use pointers nor `new`

Comment: i'd say use std::array<int, N * N > , and element with index (i , j) in matrix would have index (i*N+j) in array

Comment: ...and dont get into the habit of using `malloc` in c++, its almost never the right thing

Comment: @KcFnMi After answering I found that you have edited your question. What do you mean by  `std matrix`?

Comment: First decide whether you intend to use C or C++.  The C++ standard library provides alternatives that C does not.   And neither language has a "std matrix".

Comment: I would like to "decide whether you intend to use C or C++" latter. For now, let's say that I need to keep the malloc stuff. But I want to opperate in C++ manner in other parts.

Comment: `std::vector` is no less safe than manual memory allocation when using multithreading libraries.

Comment: @KcFnMi - then there's no option.   There is no option that is common to both C and C++ that allows you to avoid a type cast in your code.   Even less so, if you insist on using `malloc()` - when `malloc()` is used, what is good practice in C is bad practice in C++, and vice versa.   You're therefore essentially asking for a solution that is likely to be poor technique in BOTH languages.   Whichever language you use, parallel programming requires solid technique.

Comment: @KcFnMi C and C++ are different languages. If you are **lucky** what you end up with will compile without errors in **at most one** of the two. If you are **unlucky** it will compile without errors in both, and **behave differently**

Comment: You should really look at the link @Ron posted. A good implementation is there.

Comment: Avoiding `malloc` and `new` does not negatively affect the ability to use multi-thread interfaces. Your question is unclear now.

Comment: @KcFnMi: C and C++ are indeed different languages and each single source file should be one the them, but mixing C and C++ translation units in the same program is rather common: most of the C standard library is explicitely a subset of the C++ one

Comment: @Peter: it is perfectly valid to allocate some memory in one source of one language (C or C++) and *use* it in a different source file in the other language. Simply you can only exchange primitive type variables, pointers to them, or pointers to functions using only that.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - I didn't say otherwise.   I responded to a comment in which the OP effectively asked for a solution that is common to both C and C++ (i.e. can be compiled with both) not a solution that involves passing variables from one to the other.   And, although your comment about "primitive" types is not relevant to the question, they are not the only types that can be passed between C and C++ code - it is also possible, for example, with POD types.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't.

Multi-dimensional array is not the place where C++ is at its best. Here it is still acceptable because N is a compile time constant, but if it was a run-time variable you would be off because VLA are not supported in standard C++ (even if they are supported *as an implementation extension* by some implementations like gcc and clang).

So if you really need to deal with true 2D arrays, just use a custom class containing an underlying `std::array` for fixed compile time dimension or a vector for runtime dimensions for the total size and provide 2d accessors to that. As `std::arrays` and vectors are objects, you avoid the ressource copying and moving nightmare(*).

A simplified implementation could be:

```
class matrix {
   std::vector<int> vec;
   int  rows;
   int cols;

public:
   matrix(int i, int j): rows(i), cols(j), vec(i * j) {}

   int& at(int i, int j) {
       return vec[j + i * cols];
   }

   const int& at(int i, int j) const {
       return vec[j + i * cols];
   }
};
```

That way the underlying structure is still a true 2D array, and you do have methods to use it whith its 2 dimensions

What are still lacking here:

- indices and sizes should probably be `size_t` instead of `int`
- indices could be tested to be in an acceptable range in `at` methods - if you don't check them, the function should not be called `at`...
- other constructors to build a matrix on top of an existing 2D array (that could come from C legacy code for example)

Additional remark:

You say that you want to avoid vectors for possible multi-threading. First I cannot imagine why a vector would be less multi-thread safe that a manually allocated dynamic array. Second if you really need manual allocation you will have to follow the rule of three/five and implement custom copy/move constructors and assignment operator in addition to a custom destructor.

---

(*) I have the project to write a generic multi-D container supporting `operator []` and iterators, so I know that it is a rather complex task. I have already submitted a pre-version to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/173979/146901) but it is still far from being simply useable.

Comment: Your functions and constructor are private... I think it's dangerous to call a the function `at` and not implement range checking, as that is defined for STL containers. Just use `operator()` like described [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op).

Comment: @JHBonarius: Look like I forgot the `public:` keyword... Thanks a lot for noticing

Comment: @KcFnMi: If `m` is an instance of matrix, `&m.at(0,0)` will be the first element of the global array - simply it is an `int*` instead of a `void*`.

Comment: Is this answer similar to "the link @Ron posted" but using `std::vector`
 instead of `new`/`delete`?

Comment: Yes, but as it uses an underlying container, it can use the default destructor, and copy/move contructors and assignment operators. Using new delete requires custom (or deleted) versions for all of them because of the resource management problem (rule of three, rule of five)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an alias to make the call looks better:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int N = 2;

using TypeMatrix =int (*)[N]; //alias

void init_matrix(TypeMatrix matrix) { //simply use the alias
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
}


int main() {
    TypeMatrix x = (TypeMatrix)(int*)malloc(N*N*sizeof(int)); //avoid malloc
    init_matrix(x);
   }
```

Note also that you can take this to the next level by using template alias like as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int N = 2;

template<typename T , int K>
using TypeMatrix =T (*)[K];

using MatrixInt =TypeMatrix<int,N>;
using MatrixDouble =TypeMatrix<double,N>;


template <typename Matrix>
void init_matrix(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = 1.1;
}


template <typename Matrix>
void print(Matrix matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            std::cout<<matrix[i][j]<< " ";
}


int main() {
    MatrixInt x = (MatrixInt) (new int[N*N]);
    MatrixDouble y = (MatrixDouble) (new double[N*N]);
    init_matrix(x);
    init_matrix(y);
    print(x);
    print(y);
}
```

That said I highly discourage using raw pointers and mixing C and C++ (`malloc` vs `new`) for this kind of job. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Comment: still using malloc... why?

Comment: But now you have a memory leak

Comment: "linearized" that's what I get from malloc, isn't?

Comment: @JHBonarius I only intended to answer the question not to find all problems in the code. The leak was there from the beginning. Feel free to edit =)

Comment: @JHBonarius *But now you have a memory leak*: at some point of view, I think this make everybody to not use of raw pointers(at least for me). Despite this problem, I like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need dynamic allocation of contiguous integers for some reason, you can use a vector of arrays, or a smart pointer.

```
std::vector<int[N]> x(N);
std::unique_ptr<int[][N]> x = std::make_unique<int[][N]>(N);
```

Using your implementation of `init_matrix`, you can simply pass in the address of the first element.

```
init_matrix(&x[0]);
```

However, it would be preferable to pass the vector or smart pointer in by reference.

```
void init_matrix (std::vector<int[N]> &matrix) {
    ...
}

void init_matrix (std::unique_ptr<int[][N]> &matrix) {
    ...
}

...
init_matrix(x);
```

Comment: `*(int (*)[N][N])&x[0]` I'm not sure you get the right type here? A pointer to array `int [N]` is not compatible with a pointer to array `int [N][N]`. Array pointers, unlike arrays, do not decay. `int (**)[N]` is not compatible with `int (*)[N][N]` nor `int (*)[N]`.

Comment: It is a reinterpret cast, so `&x[0]` is not a `int (*)[N][N]`. The cast is coercing it to such a pointer, and then dereferencing it to get the array type to pass to the function.

Comment: The cast and dereference violate the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @aschepler: Unclear, since the pointer value that was generated by the converted array in an expression should be allowed to be cast back to the original array somehow.

Comment: @jxh Very unlikely that the `vector` implementation created an `int[N][N]` object.  More likely an `unsigned char[N*N*sizeof(int)]` object or similar, then several individual `int[N]` objects in the same storage.

Comment: @jxh Although, hmm, the actual usage of `m` doesn't actually lvalue-to-rvalue `m`, if that's even possible for array lvalues.

Comment: @aschepler: Every row of `m` is treated as `int[N]`, which is the type returned by `x[i]`.

Comment: @aschepler: No matter how the allocator did it, the object being pointed to is allowed to be accessed as such an object.

Comment: @aschepler: Got rid of that part, since it wasn't really the point I wanted to emphasize.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding bad practice of using `malloc` in C++, then...

You can replace the array pointer in the function parameter with an array. This will decay right back to an array pointer, but it makes the function interface a bit clearer.

You can't convert between `int(*)[N]` and `(int*)` in neither C nor C++. They are not compatible pointer types. Even if they point at the very same address, you will get undefined behavior problems caused by strict pointer aliasing.

You *could* rewrite the code like this, but it's not really recommended either:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int N = 2;

void init_matrix(int matrix[N][N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = 1;
}

int main() {
    int (*x)[N] = (int(*)[N])malloc(N*N*sizeof(int));
    init_matrix(*x);
}
```

I wouldn't recommend it in C++ - this style is quite cumbersome without the VLA feature of C. In C++ it is probably wiser to use `std::array&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using `std::vector` for multi-threaded programming, for instance explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9307403/6717178). Any other storage is just as dangerous.

Apart from all the vector examples shown in the other answers: If you are using fixed-size matrices, you could even consider going to templates based on `std::array`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <class T, size_t rows, size_t cols>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix() {}
    Matrix(T init) { data.fill(init); }
    double& operator() (size_t row, size_t col)
    {
        if (row < rows && col < cols) return data[cols*row + col];
        throw std::out_of_range("Matrix subscript out of bounds.");
    }
    double operator() (size_t row, size_t col) const
    {
        return data(row, col);
    }
private:
    std::array<T, rows*cols> data;
};

int main()
{
    Matrix<double, 2, 2> mat(1.0);
    mat(1,1) = 2.3;
    std::cout << "mat(1,1) = " << mat(1,1) << std::endl;
}
```

p.s. invalid size checking implemented in the example.