# Find all primes in a range between two numbers using a given amount of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

The problem is to use a given amount of threads to calculate all prime numbers between two numbers. The threads should do an even amount of work.

I am very new to both C++ and threads, and I am having some issues with getting the threads to, first of all, find the prime numbers, and second, to do an even amount of work.

The find_prime function is working when I run it with only one thread, but with multiple threads I get a heap-buffer-overflow or something I don't quite understand. My approach could be very wrong, but my thought process is that each thread should start to search for prime numbers concurrently, and if they find one, they should check if another thread already has found it. If not, the prime number is added to the primes vector.

The error message is very long, but the summary says:

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x43c58) in __asan_memcpy
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:

  0x1c04000003b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c04000003c0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c04000003d0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c04000003e0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c04000003f0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x1c0400000400:[fa]fa 04 fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000410: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000420: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000430: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000440: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0400000450: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void find_prime(int low, int high, vector<int> &primes) {
  bool is_prime = true;
  int i, j;

  for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    if (i == 1 || i == 0)
      continue;

    is_prime = true;

    for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; ++j) {
      if (i % j == 0) {
        is_prime = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (is_prime && (std::find(primes.begin(), primes.end(), i) != primes.end()))
      continue;

    if (is_prime) {
      primes.push_back(i);
    }
  }
}

void print(std::vector<int> const &primes) {
  for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << primes.at(i) << ' ';
  }
}

int main() {

  int low = 0, high = 100, num_threads = 4, i;

  std::vector<int> primes;
  std::vector<thread> threads;

  for (i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
    std::thread t([&](int low, int high) {
      find_prime(low, high, primes);
    },
                  low, high);
    threads.push_back(std::move(t));
  }

  for (auto &thread : threads)
    thread.join();

  print(primes);
  cout << "\nSize: " << primes.size();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error you're getting, i.e. the heap-buffer-overflow message.

Comment: The base problem is that you can't have multiple threads writing to the same vector at the same time. But ask yourself: What in your code will tell your threads to do different work, or are all you threads doing the same work?

Comment: About std::vector thread-safety: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305315/stdvector-thread-safety-multi-threading

Answer (score 1):

The code above has several problems.

- It calculates 4 times all prime numbers in the range. So, it is much slower, than without threads
- You even noticed that and put a

```
if (is_prime && (std::find(primes.begin(), primes.end(), i) != primes.end()))
      continue;
```

in your code, to check, if a number was already calculated. Then you would not store it. This makes it even slower.

- You write in 4 treads in paralell to a `std::vector`. Writing to a `std::vector` is not thread safe. You would need to add `std::mutex`es or other syncronization mechanisms to prevent the problem.
- That is most probably also the reason for the crash
- You need to split your range, e.g. 0..100 into equal parts, for example 0..25, 26..50,  51..75,  76..100. And this you will give to your 4 threads. Then, each thread calculates only a chunk.
- Then, you should use `std::promise`s and `std::future`s, to excahnge data with your threads.
- You should use unsigned values for indices

---

Now a little explanation on the claculation of equal ranges. Splitting a range into **somehow** equal parts is easy. We calculate the delta beween low and high and do a integer division by the number of desired groups. This may work with or without a remainder. We can get the remainder by a modulo division.

Then we would get something like

```
    const size_t delta = high+1 - low;
    const size_t chunk = delta / numberOfGroups;
    size_t remainder = delta % numberOfGroups;
```

Please note: The remainder is of course always smaller than the number of groups. Example, if you do a modulo division by 4, then the remainder can be only 0,1,2,3. Never more. If we have a remainder, then we equally distribute this to the chunks. So, we can write a very simple function like the below:

```
// Calculate start and end index for all chunks
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> calculatePairs(const size_t low, const size_t high, const size_t numberOfGroups) {

    // Here we will store the resulting pairs with start and end values
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> pairs{};

    // Calculate chung size and remainder
    const size_t delta = high+1 - low;
    const size_t chunk = delta / numberOfGroups;
    size_t remainder = delta % numberOfGroups;

    // Calculate the chunks start and end addresses for all chunks
    size_t startIndex{}, endIndex{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; ++i) {

        // Calculate end address and distribute remainder equally
        endIndex = startIndex + chunk + (remainder ? 1 : 0) - 1;
        // Store a new pair of start and end indices
        pairs.emplace_back(startIndex, endIndex);
        // Nexct start index
        startIndex = endIndex + 1;
        // We now consumed 1 remainder
        if (remainder) --remainder;
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

This will calculate `std::pair`s with start end end indices for each requested group. In the line

```
endIndex = startIndex + chunk + (remainder ? 1 : 0) - 1;
```

we do the distribution of the remainder. If there is a remainder, then we add 1 to the current end-index. Then we subtract 1 from the remainder, because we just distributed 1 out of it.

Ok. Now we have the pairs. These pairs of high and low indices can be given to our threaded prime calculator.

---

Next. Exchange of data between `std::thread`s and/or the main program: For that C++ offers so called `std::promise`s and `std::future`s. Many people have a hard time to understand these. Please check also cppreference.

Very simply said:

- A `std::promise` is a "thing", where you promise that a thread will return a "value" in the future. Your thread will store the value in the `std::promise` by using its ````set```function.
- With a `future` you can retrieve the value that has been stored in the `promise` by using the `get` function of the `std::future`.  It will also wait, until the data is available.

This was very simplified. But maybe it helps a little to understand the mechanism.

---

Please see your modified code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <utility>

// Calculate start and end index for all chunks
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> calculatePairs(const size_t low, const size_t high, const size_t numberOfGroups) {

    // Here we will store the resulting pairs with start and end values
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> pairs{};

    // Calculate chung size and remainder
    const size_t delta = high+1 - low;
    const size_t chunk = delta / numberOfGroups;
    size_t remainder = delta % numberOfGroups;

    // Calculate the chunks start and end addresses for all chunks
    size_t startIndex{}, endIndex{};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfGroups; ++i) {

        // Calculate end address and distribute remainder equally
        endIndex = startIndex + chunk + (remainder ? 1 : 0) - 1;
        // Store a new pair of start and end indices
        pairs.emplace_back(startIndex, endIndex);
        // Nexct start index
        startIndex = endIndex + 1;
        // We now consumed 1 remainder
        if (remainder) --remainder;
    }
    return pairs;
}


void find_prime(const size_t low, const size_t high, std::promise<std::vector<int>>&& promisePrimes) {
    bool is_prime = true;

    std::vector<int> primes{};

    for (size_t i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == 0)
            continue;

        is_prime = true;

        for (size_t j = 2; j <= i / 2; ++j) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (is_prime) {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    promisePrimes.set_value(std::move(primes));
}

void print(std::vector<int> const& primes) {
    for (std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << primes.at(i) << ' ';
    }
}

int main() {

    constexpr size_t low = 0, high = 100, num_threads = 4;

    
    std::vector<int> primes;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> pairs = calculatePairs(low, high, num_threads);

    std::vector<std::promise<std::vector<int>>> promisePrimes(num_threads);
    std::vector<std::shared_future<std::vector<int>>> futurePrimes(num_threads);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {

        futurePrimes[i] = promisePrimes[i].get_future();

        std::thread t(find_prime, pairs[i].first, pairs[i].second, std::move(promisePrimes[i]));
        threads.push_back(std::move(t));
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        std::vector<int> temp = futurePrimes[i].get();
        primes.insert(primes.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
        threads[i].join();
    }

    print(primes);
    std::cout << "\nSize: " << primes.size();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Please note: I use a `std::shared_future`, because I want to store it in a `std::vector` and "normal" `std::future`s cannot be copied.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in your example is basically doing the same work with all of your threads, which is not very efficient :)

Based on your question I assume that you are not looking for the most efficient solution here, but rather would like to get familiar with multithreading in c++. The general approach I recommend is split the original range into  exclusive ranges (eg. for 2 threads split the range [0, 99] to [0, 49] and [50, 99]), find the prime numbers in each of these ranges on different threads, return the results to the main thread and combine the results there.

In order to do this I recomend getting familiar with `futures` and `promises` as well to be able to return something from a spawned thread. [Here is a site](https://thispointer.com/c11-multithreading-part-8-stdfuture-stdpromise-and-returning-values-from-thread/) I've just found that explains them and also other multithreading concepts in c++.